# Tableview search, cuts display

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hey guys I simply can't solve this problem i've got.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/riuM1.png

I have tried setting bounds of the UITableView like so:

```
[tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, 320, self.view.size.height)];
```

That didn't seem to fix my problem(See picture above), I thought maybe it was some clipping under the settings of the search bar which it wasn't.

I also tried setting the size of the UITableView that didn't help me.

It's also weird when using the UITableView without searching it works fine and the cells go full size.
But as soon as i search it starts clipping like that.

I've tried searching on the internet for a solution, i don't seem to find anything.

here is the rest of my search code:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    UIButton *cancelButton;
    UIView *topView = controller.searchBar.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }

}
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF beginsWith[cd] '%@'", searchText];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    searchResults = [combine filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check size of the table view for the UISearchDisplayController:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView  description]);
```